# Can't get event.target.id to match in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have three buttons nested within the `buttons` variable a form that are all supposed to play a certain song if the buttons within the nested element are clicked. The code to check which buttons are pressed is:

```
//buttons variable that the three button elements are nested in
const buttons = document.getElementById('music-choice');

//the buttons themselves
const canonButton = document.getElementById('canonButton');
const moonlightButton = document.getElementById('moonlightButton');
const _40thButton = document.getElementById('40thButton');

//variables connected to the audio elements
const canonMusic = document.querySelector('audio[id="canon"]')
const moonlightMusic = document.querySelector('audio[id="moonlight"]')
const _40thMusic = document.querySelector('audio[id="40th"]')

buttons.addEventListener('click', musicPlayer(event)); //this is js.20

function musicPlayer(event) {
    if (event.target.id === 'moonlightButton') { //this is js.23
        moonlightMusic.play();
    }
    else if (event.target.id === 'canonButton') {
        canonMusic.play();
    }
    else if (event.target.id === '40thButton') {
        _40thMusic.play();
    }
}
```

However, everytime I try to run this code I get this error message in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
> at musicPlayer (index.js:23)
> at index.js:20

When I use the console log of those event objects, it says that the event.target.id is `moonlightButton`, so I would assume that having it equal to the string `moonlightButton` would trigger those if and else if statements but that isn't the case. I have tried this with classnames and values and have no luck with any of them so far. I'm  new to Javascript so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `buttons.addEventListener('click', musicPlayer(event))` this is incorrect, you are *executing* the function passing in a *non-existent* parameter `event`. You just need to use the function reference when adding the listener -> `buttons.addEventListener('click', musicPlayer)`

Comment: haha that solved it. I guess I still gotta get the event concept fully down. Thank you so much for explaining it to me.

Answer (score 0):

As vlaz has pointed out, I was trying to pass in a nonexistent parameter to my event listener.